# CakePHP hasAndBelongsToMany not linking as expected

Tags: php, cakephp

I have three tables: Users, Profiles, and Friends.

They are connected like so:

```
public $name = 'User';

    public $hasOne = 'Profile';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Post',
        'Answer'
    );

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User'=>array(
            'className'              => 'User',
            'joinTable'              => 'friends',
            'foreignKey'             => 'user_from',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'user_to'
        )
    );
```

and the profile model is just a belongsTo user so I have not shown that, and the friends model is virtual by doing the association in the user model.

So to get a list of friends for a user. I pass the username like so in the friends controller:

```
public function index( $username )
{   
    $friends = $this->User->find('first', 
        array(
            'conditions'=>array(
               'User.username'=>$username
            ),
            'contain'=>array(
                'Profile',
                'Friend'=>array(
                    'conditions'=>array(
                        'Friend.status'=>1
                    ),
                    'contain'=>'Profile'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $this->set('friends', $friends);
}
```

Which should pull the data for the friends and there associated Profile info!

However I get this error: `Model "Friend" is not associated with model "Profile" [APP/Cake/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]` so something isn't working correctly...

Can anyone help?

I tried changing the name of he hasAndBelongsToMany to Friends in the model but that throw an error that the table wasn't unqiue... so that's not the solution either.

Tables:

```
**users**
id
username
password

**profiles**
id
name
user_id

**friends**
id
user_from
user_to
status
```

If I change the Model to become:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Friend'=>array(
            'className'              => 'Friend',
            'joinTable'              => 'friends',
            'foreignKey'             => 'user_from',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'user_to'
        )
    );
```

then I get this error:

```
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'Friend'

SQL Query: SELECT `Friend`.`id`, `Friend`.`user_from`, `Friend`.`user_to`, `Friend`.`created`, `Friend`.`status`, `Friend`.`id`, `Friend`.`user_from`, `Friend`.`user_to`, `Friend`.`created`, `Friend`.`status` FROM `db52704_favorr`.`friends` AS `Friend` JOIN `db52704_favorr`.`friends` AS `Friend` ON (`Friend`.`user_from` = 6 AND `Friend`.`user_to` = `Friend`.`id`)
```

Comment: It may be outdated for you, but it may be helpful for someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Models and aliases of related models should be unique. In your case the problem is:

```
public $name = 'User';
...
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User'=>array(
    ...
```

If `friends` is the join table name, than you could use `Friend` as the alias of the friend User.

Second thing is you're trying to contain both `User => Profile` and `User => Friend => Profile` which is probably also problematic.

In my experience, deep `contain`s can get quite inefficient. You might consider dropping the Friend's `Profile` from the contain, and then extracting the friend user ids and getting the profiles separately.

Comment: Well the issue happened when using Friend as the alias rather than User so effectively reverse of what you said. In any case I'm still not understanding the problem here :/

Comment: The user model you gave didn't have a `Friend` association, but your contain clause did include `Friend`. How come? My advice was to try to avoid unique aliases.

Comment: Could you shown an example of what you mean and how I could fix this, as if you look at my updated post I tried using Friend instead but it causes the error shown... So not sure what to do..

Comment: Oh, I meant try `public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Friend'=>array(
            'className'              => 'User'`. You don't need a `Friend` model for the habtm.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Friend` model has no `user_id` and thats why `User` model can't make contact with `Friend`. Try with the following:

```
public function index( $username )
{   
    $this->User->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
    $friends = $this->User->find('first', 
        array(
            'conditions'=>array(
               'User.username'=>$username
            ),
            'contain'=>array(
                'Profile',
                'Friend'=>array(
                    'conditions'=>array(
                        'Friend.status'=>1
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $this->set('friends', $friends);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work either! If I debug the $friends it just pulls out the user and profile info for that user and not the friends.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

User.php

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Friend'=>array(
        'className'              => 'User',
        'joinTable'              => 'friends',
        'foreignKey'             => 'user_from',
        'associationForeignKey'  => 'user_to'
    )
);
```

This will alias the User table as a Friend to itself in a habtm relationship. To keep with convention, the join table should be called `friends_users` with `user_id` and `friend_id` keys.

Here's the result I get with a test app I made (just add your conditions):

```
$this->User->contain(array(
            'Profile',
            'Friend' => array(
                'Profile',
            ),
        ));
debug($this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => 1))));

array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'user1'
        ),
        'Profile' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '1'
        ),
        'Friend' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'name' => 'user2',
                'FriendsUser' => array(
                    'id' => '1',
                    'user_id' => '1',
                    'friend_id' => '2'
                ),
                'Profile' => array(
                    'id' => '2',
                    'user_id' => '2'
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```